# Why can my VB6 app not open the "Open" dialog on some systems

Tags: dialog, vb6, runtime-error

I have a VB6 application that, despite everything manages to work on lots of systems, including the numerous Windows 7 x64 systems.

On most of them, the windows dialogs accessed through COMDLG32.OCX work just fine. However, on one particular system, this doesn't work at all. Some forms, when attempting to show the "Open" (or "Save") dialog causes an exception:

> Run-time error '32765'
>
> The common dialog function failed during initalization. This error often occurs when insufficent memory is available

Although some other forms that use it simply never show the dialog box at all. Needless to say, memory is not an issue. Microsoft have a [kb article on the error](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/888167) where they say:

> You have a Microsoft Visual Basic 6.0 program that runs on a Terminal Server, the program uses the Common Dialog control to open a file, and the following conditions are true:
>
> - The user is using a roaming profile.
> - There is a policy to delete the roaming profile when the user logs off.
>
> When these conditions are true, you may receive [the error quoted above]
>   The conditions mentioned are not true - this is all through the (only, local) user on the system. The suggested solution involves calling the relevant API calls directly.

Reluctant to implemenet the pile of code suggested in every form relevant, I found a class already built for the purpose - [CDlgEx](http://www.freevbcode.com/ShowCode.asp?ID=631). While this works fine on all the computers where the OCX also works fine, on the system which has problems, whenver this line is reached:

```
RetValue = GetOpenFileName(OFN)
```

where

```
Private Declare Function GetOpenFileName Lib "comdlg32.dll" Alias "GetOpenFileNameA" (pOpenfilename As OPENFILENAME) As Long
```

and OFN is of the private type expected by the function, nothing happens. No dialog box appears, and the program simply moves on to the next line.

Further testing has shown that this only happens when running from the IDE. Running from a compliled executable, everything is fine.

Comment: The IDE and Compiler are not compatible for x64 systems, only 32 bit systems. Compiled programs are compatible with x64.

Comment: The VB6 IDE/Compiler works fine on x64 systems.

Answer (score 0):

Had the exact same problem. Grab the cCommonDialog class from the following link and add it to your project.

https://github.com/ziggythehamster/ignitionserver/blob/master/vbtracer/cCommonDialog.cls

You can then do something like this in your code

```
Private Sub Command1_Click()
    Dim commonDialog As New GCommonDialog
    Dim fileName As String

    commonDialog.VBGetOpenFileName fileName

    MsgBox fileName
End Sub
```